# PHP MySQL print monthly data using array() not work

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code for show monthly data using php and mysql:

```
$sql = "SELECT title,timestamp,id FROM ".NEWS." ORDER BY timestamp DESC";

$data = DataAccess::Fetch($sql);

$nav = array();

foreach ( $data as $news ) {
    $month = date('F', $news['timestamp']);
    $nav[$month][$news['id']] = $news['title'];
}
```

Now In `var_export($nav)` My result is false:

```
array (
  'July' => 
  array (
    277 => 'title1 for July 2016',
    276 => 'title2 for July 2016',
    275 => 'title3 for July 2016',
    273 => 'title4 for July 2016',
    272 => 'title5 for July 2016',
    274 => 'title1 for July 2015',
    264 => 'title2 for July 2015',
    261 => 'title3 for July 2015',
  ),
 'January' => 
   array (
    243 => 'title for January 2016',
    242 => 'title for January 2015',
  ), 
)
```

In result I see marge data for July 2016 with data with July 2015 Or Merge data for January 2016 With January 2015. I need to Separated Data For July 2016 from July 2015 And January 2016 From January 2015. How do fix problem?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Sure, If I add `$year = date('Y', $news['timestamp']);` and `$nav[$year][$month][$news['id']] = $news['title'];` this worked But I need to Only print each month with data. my mean is: print data from database for each month.

Comment: You mean you want to only show `2016 - July` data in the report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only using the MONTH `$month = date('F', $news['timestamp']);` as the key to your $nav array. You also need to use the year if you dont want to mix the year data together.

I suggest something like this possibly

```
$nav = array();

foreach ( $data as $news ) {
    $year = date('Y', $news['timestamp'] );
    $month = date('F', $news['timestamp']);
    $nav[$year][$month][$news['id']] = $news['title'];
}
```

Or maybe

```
$nav = array();

foreach ( $data as $news ) {
    $year = date('Y', $news['timestamp'] );
    $month = date('F', $news['timestamp']);
    $nav[$year . '-' . $month][$news['id']] = $news['title'];
}
```